# How to hide the navigator tools during the present mode of Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

In the full screen (slideshow) mode of Google Slides, there is a big navigator on the left bottom side. There are two fundamental problems with it:

1. The navigator pops up whenever you move the pointer (mouse) which is very distracting to the audience.
2. The navigator conceals content of the slides lying in that corner.

I wonder, can I hide the annoying slide navigator?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a workaround that seems to solve the problem.

When in Google Drive, right click on the presentation file and select preview. Then, select the full-screen option from the bottom bar.

[image]

Comment: I see not option "preview", could you please add an image showing where it is?

Answer (score 4):

You can install uBlock Origin Chrome extension and select what element you want to hide.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ublock-origin/cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm

Add custom filter (in settings)

```
docs.google.com##.punch-viewer-nav-rounded-container
```

Comment: Google no longer uses the `.punch-viewer-nav-v2` class for the navigation bar, use the `.punch-viewer-nav-rounded-container` class instead

Comment: This is now `.punch-viewer-navbar-translucent.punch-viewer-navbar`.

Answer (score 3):

When presenting, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to make the bar smaller.
When it is small enough, it would not be annoying and not easy to be triggered.

Answer (score 2):

You can also activate captions (hit CC), and the navigator will no longer block the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can just change the URL.
Look for the `/edit` or the `/present` on the URL and replace by `/preview` instead.

`/edit`

[image]

`/present`

[image]

`/preview`

[image]